# Multidisplay Rendering

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build a project on 4 screens (2x projectors and 2x monitors all running at 1024x768). I'm using 2xGTX 295s.

Every time I run the file (using -multidisplay) the main screen hangs black and if I look at the processes I see 3 other screens being created, but nothing ever appears. The log files say "D3D11:failed to create RenderTexture(1024 x 768 fmt 44 aa 8), error 0x8007000e" where each Display.Activate() code should execute.

Relevant code:

```
    if (Display.displays.Length > 1) {
        Display.displays [1].SetRenderingResolution (1024, 768);
        Display.displays [1].Activate ();
    }
    if (Display.displays.Length > 2){
        Display.displays [2].SetRenderingResolution (1024, 768);
        Display.displays [2].Activate ();
    }
    if (Display.displays.Length > 3) {
        Display.displays [3].SetRenderingResolution (1024, 768);
        Display.displays [3].Activate ();
    }
```

I've tried searching for a solution, but because multi-display is relatively new I can't seem to find anything on it.

Does anyone have a solution or idea? it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Alright. I just wanted to update in case anyone else had this problem. The issue occurred when the native resolutions weren't the same on the screens. All the resolutions should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a driver issue. Windows update probably updated your video driver. Update your driver from **device manager**. If that didn't work, use a video driver from the manufacturer of your PC.You can easily download this from their website. Will provide link if you update your question with name of your PC make, the model number and the Operating System.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't reply at the time. The problem was fixed partially by using a more up-to-date graphics card and partially by making sure all the screens were 1920x1080.